# Save java GUI by using javaBeans Persistence mechanism

Tags: java, swing, javabeans

I want to use JavaBeans Persistence mechanism to save my GUI to local disk. The problem that I faced is to save two frames at one time. Here is my code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BeansTest {
  private static JFileChooser chooser;
private JFrame frame;

public static void main(String[] args){
    chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
    BeansTest test = new BeansTest();
    test.init();
}

public void init(){
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("PersistentFrameTest");
    frame.setSize(400,200);

    JButton registryButton = new JButton("Registry");
    frame.add(registryButton);
    registryButton.addActionListener(EventHandler.create(ActionListener.class, this, "registry"));

    JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save");
    frame.add(saveButton);
    saveButton.addActionListener(EventHandler.create(ActionListener.class, this, "save"));

    frame.setVisible(true);
}


public void registry(){

 Registry re = new Registry();
}

public void save()
{
    if(chooser.showSaveDialog(null)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        try{
            File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(new FileOutputStream(file));
            encoder.writeObject(frame);
            encoder.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
}

}



public class Registry {

public Registry(){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setSize(400,200);

    JLabel nameL = new JLabel("Name:");
    JTextField nameF = new JTextField(8);

    frame.add(nameL);
    frame.add(nameF);


    frame.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

I want to save two frames at the same when I press the saveButton. Now I can only save the main frame. Please help me solve this problem. Many Thanks.

Comment: So why exactly can't you save a second frame?

Comment: So from what I can tell, you can't save the JFrame contained in the Registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `JFrame` in the `Registry` class is not accessible you will need to add a getter to this class. Then, given that the `Registry` creation is dependent on an `ActionListener`, you will need to check that your Registry handle `re` has been instantiated before saving *that* frame. In code:

Add to `Registry`:

```
public JFrame getFrame() {
   return frame;
}
```

Add to `BeansTest.save()`:

```
if (re.getFrame() != null) {
   encoder.writeObject(re.getFrame());
}
```

Some variables here will need to be moved to global scope. I think that you will benefit from figuring out these bits yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your response! But I do not know how to modify the code. Could you please help me change the code above?

Comment: It works! Thanks. But when I read the generated XML file I get these two frames. Is it possible to get the main frame only and when a user press the registry button, the second frame appears?

Comment: Your read logic is not presented here so perhaps ths would be better in a new question posting :)